# seting setText failure after onActivityResult

Tags: android, settext

I use `ViewPager+Tabhost` framework.

I pass `startActivityForResult(B activity,100),` in a Activity. And pass `setResult(200, data);` in B.

It can receive the value from B in A:`String b = data.getStringExtra("b");`

It can also see the value use Log.

But it can not set the value use `tv.setText(b);` in A. I can not set the value use `tv.setText(“dasfasd”);` either. I do not the reason.

Why It can not set the value？

Comment: Post your code. It should work this way.

Comment: What exactly happens? The application crashes, or the TextView simply remains empty? Also you should post the code and the layout, it's impossible to understand the problem based on your description.

Comment: @bonnie is it throwing any error in logcat when you call `tv.setText(b);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Activity_A.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {    
        public void run() {
            tv.setText("dasfasd");    
        }
});
```